# Find and match value of array from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let mine = [
 {food: 'beef', soda: 'coke'},
 {food: 'milk', soda: 'juice'}
]
```

```
let yours = [
 [{food: 'beef', sport: 'a', song: 'a'}],
 [{food: 'milk', sport: 'b', song: 'c'}],
 [{food: 'pork', sport: 'b', song: 'c'}],
]
```

I want to find same 'value(beef and milk)' of 'mine' and 'yours'. So I used map() and filter().

```
result = [
 [{food: 'beef', sport: 'a', song: 'a'}],
 [{food: 'milk', sport: 'b', song: 'c'}],
]
```

```
yours.map(data => {
  const same = mine.filter(obj => {
    return data[0].food == obj.food
 })
  return same
})
```

My code works but any more elegant way?

Comment: Questions asking for "elegant" ways are off-topic because they are opinion-based. See [What types of questions can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the optimal ways is, create a new object using the `mine` array then filter the `yours` array and keep those items that exist at the object created before.

```js
let mine = [
 {food: 'beef', soda: 'coke'},
 {food: 'milk', soda: 'juice'}
];

let yours = [
 [{food: 'beef', sport: 'a', song: 'a'}],
 [{food: 'milk', sport: 'b', song: 'c'}],
 [{food: 'pork', sport: 'b', song: 'c'}],
];

const dishes = Object.fromEntries(
  mine.map(({food, soda}) => ([food, soda]))
);

const result = yours.filter(dish => dishes?.[dish[0].food]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: super useful.... why did you use  '?.'    dishes?.[dish[0].food]    could you explain?

Comment: The `?.` is called __Optional Chaining__. For more check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining